# The proper formula of sucrose: why both forms are correct and how one is transformed into another?

Tags: organic-chemistry, structural-formula, carbohydrates

During preparations for my exam I've stumbled upon a tormenting question how it happens that the formula of sucrose is written in two different forms: the vertical and the horizontal ones:

- **The horizontal form**

  [image: the horizontal form]
- **The vertical form**

  [image: the vertical form]

The vertical one seems quite obvious and logical when you know that the hydroxyl group on the second carbon in β-ᴅ-fructose directs up, but in the horizontal and more popular form the −OH directs as it was alpha form what's not true. How does it happen that both are correct?

Comment: Imagine (or assemble, if you can) a ball-and-stick model of sucrose. Now start slowly turning the fructose half around the bond between glucose and the bridging oxygen.

Comment: The stacked form is simplified so the C-O-C bond looks linear, but it's actually bent like an elbow as in the horizontal display. Rotate about that bond and one of the rings is turned upside down _relative to your viewpoint_, but otherwise remains the same.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43600/structure-of-sucrose

Comment: Grab the six-membered ring and move the five-membered ring upside-down while taking care of the relative $\ce{OH}$ configurations. The vertical form will transform into the horizontal one and vice-versa.

Comment: I want to thank you all for your answers. It helped me a lot.

Comment: Aaah, that linked duplicate question looks horrible; this looks much cleaner. Can’t we close the other one that already has a negative score as a dupe of this one?

Comment: @Jan It's not a duplicate in the first place.